# How to replace cells in a larger Pandas dataframe with cells from a smaller dataframe

Tags: pandas, replace, find, conditional-statements

I have two pandas dataframes:

Smaller:

[image]

Larger:
[image]

I want to match on the Ticker and Year and then replace the numbers in the First and Last columns with those from the smaller dataframe.

I've tried using pd.merge but I succeeded only in adding rows or columns not replacing the specific cells. Can someone please post some code that would achieve this?

Comment: you'll likely need to use `pandas.merge` and there are already so many questions on this website about that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and `suffixes` and then [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with rename for remove `_`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Ticker':list('abcdef'),
                   'Year':[2013,2014,2013,2014,2013,2014],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'Last':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'First':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

print (df1)
   C  F  First  Last Ticker  Year
0  7  a      5     1      a  2013
1  8  a      3     3      b  2014
2  9  a      6     5      c  2013
3  4  b      9     7      d  2014
4  2  b      2     1      e  2013
5  3  b      4     0      f  2014

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'First':[4,5,4,5],
                   'Last':[7,8,9,4],
                   'Year':[2013,2014,2014,2015],
                   'Ticker':list('aabc')})

print (df2)
   First  Last Ticker  Year
0      4     7      a  2013
1      5     8      a  2014
2      4     9      b  2014
3      5     4      c  2015
```

---

```
df = df1.merge(df2, suffixes=('_',''), on=['Ticker','Year'], how='left')
df1[['First','Last']] = (df[['First','Last']].combine_first(df[['First_','Last_']]
                                             .rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_'))))

print (df1)
   C  F  First  Last Ticker  Year
0  7  a    4.0   7.0      a  2013
1  8  a    4.0   9.0      b  2014
2  9  a    6.0   5.0      c  2013
3  4  b    9.0   7.0      d  2014
4  2  b    2.0   1.0      e  2013
5  3  b    4.0   0.0      f  2014
```

Comment: Hi @Jezrael, could you pls check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48699907/error-unbalanced-parenthesis-while-checking-if-an-item-presents-in-a-pandas-d

Comment: Thanks, I add answer.

Comment: This works but it leaves the First_ and Last_ columns, was that what you expect?