# merge dataframe and manage _y and _x

Tags: pandas

HJello guys,

I wanzt to do a left join like below, but im gotting date1_x, date1_y and date2_x and date2_y. What i want is to replace the column if it exists.

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='id', how='left')
```

df1

id, date1, val1,  date2

```
1,  '2021-03-10', 'XEP', '2021-04-10'
```

df2

```
 id,    date1,      date2
 1,  '2021-09-03', '2021-09-04'
 2,  '2021-09-05', '2021-09-06'
 3,  '2021-09-07', '2021-09-08'
```

expected resulting df:

```
1,  '2021-09-03', 'XEP' , '2021-09-04'
```

Comment: sorry, do you try dupe solution? If yes, why not mentioned in question and explianed why failed?

Comment: what do you mean by dupe solution please?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48699845/2901002)

Comment: yes thank you saw this !! and didn't succed

Comment: You are right wrong dupe, need `df11 = df1.set_index('id')
df22 = df2.set_index('id')

df11.update(df22)`

Comment: like you did, i have still the date1_x and date1_y and date2_x and date2_y

Comment: no merge necessary, do you try comment solution?

Comment: which ? one .? @jezrael

Comment: i tried yours. But my column id disappear totally now.

Comment: do you knwo how to do? please?

Comment: @jezrael have you an idea please?